# making authorized calls to Twitter API with node-oauth and passport

Tags: node.js, twitter, oauth, passport.js

I have OAuth set up with passport-twitter, and login and authentication is working fine. The problem comes when trying to do an authorized requests like updating status.

```
   passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({                                                                                                      
         consumerKey: config.twitter.clientID                                                                                              
       , consumerSecret: config.twitter.clientSecret                                                                                       
       , callbackURL: config.twitter.callback_url || 'http://' + config.domain + '/auth/twitter/callback'                                  
     },                                                                                                                                    
     function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {                                                                                                                    
         Player.findOne({ 'twitter.id': profile.id }, function (err, player) {                                                               

         if (err) { return done(err) }                                                                                                     
         if (!player) {                                                                                                                    
           var player = new Player({                                                                                                       
                          name: profile.displayName                                                                                                                                                                              
                        , twitter: profile._json                                                      
                        , twitter_token: token                                                                                             
                        , twitter_tokenSecret: tokenSecret                                                                                                                                                                                
                        })                                                                                                                 
           player.save(function (err, player) {                                                                                            
               if (err) log.error(err);                                                                                                    
               return done(err, player);
           })                                                                                                                              
         }                                                                                                                                 
         else {                                                                                                                            

            return done(err, player)                                                                                                                     
         }                                                                                                                                 
       })                                                                                                                                  
     }                                                                                                                                     
   ))
```

So this saves the Player via mongoose and works. I save the token and tokenSecret given by passport, and assume they have been generated with `oAuth().getOAuthRequestToken()` as part of the original callback from Twitter, and so should be valid for the rest of the given login session. (maybe a bad assumption?)

Later, when we want to tweet something for the user, having fetched the Player record and its associated token+secret:

```
 function twitter_oauth() {                                                                                                                
     return new OAuth (                                                                                                                    
         "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",                                                                                    
         "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token",                                                                                     
         keys.consumerKey,                                                                                                                 
         keys.consumerSecret,                                                                                                              
         "1.0",                                                                                                                            
         null,                                                                                                                             
         "HMAC-SHA1"                                                                                                                       
     )                                                                                                                                     
 } 

 ....

   twitter_oauth().post(api_endpoint, token, secret, body, "application/json",                                                       
                        function (error, data, res) {                                                                                      
                            if (error) {                                                                                                   
                                console.error(error)                                                                                       
                            } else {                                                                                                       
                                console.log('tweet sent')                                                                                  
                            }                                                                                                              
                        }                                                                                                                  
   )
```

The response to this is just status 401 and "Could not authenticate with OAuth."

So, am I missing something important? I have yet to dig into the passport source to find out what `token` and `tokenSecret` arguments actually are, but asking here hoping someone would point out the major flaw in the above.

Comment: found the actual params being posted, they seem to all be there and reasonable:

    POST /1/statuses/update.json 
    HTTP/1.1\r
    Authorization: OAuth 
oauth_consumer_key="QtYPhe8Es3ohYs69JhR9UQ",oauth_nonce="9ywy2s
eTxJPFobX5vaYWahoU0v1QVd4a",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1354253395",oauth_token="17236341-ldvJkClcdwbk1Naax7KBHRgwso7o4
GtzxGpLPAks",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="Ut5XGNA0Za4PlVQkgXoMJELY0Jo%3D"
    Host: api.twitter.com

Answer (score 1):

Try to see if your application settings on dev.twitter.com are set to read & write.

Also check the timestamp in the header, if it's 5 minutes off to twitter's server clock the request will fail.

You could also try another library, I've used [node-oauth](https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth) or you could try [ntwitter](https://github.com/AvianFlu/ntwitter) which is based on node-oauth.

Comment: good ideas, but the settings are correct and the server time is updated with ntp. passport uses `node-oauth`, so that's what I'm already using. I'll look into ntwitter but hoping to stay with the stack we have. Do you know if there is any verification step that is needed before the `/statuses/update` call, or if the token/secret returned from passport should be good enough?

Comment: `ntwitter` also results in a 401 (code 32) when used with the same token/secret as we get in the `verify` callback above in `TwitterStrategy`. So it seems something is wrong with the generation of the token, no idea what

Comment: I suggest you use version 1.1 because v1 is deprecated. I know Twitter can be a pain in the ass and their error message is terrible. I don't know in how far passport-twitter handle's the callbacks for the request_token requests which return the oauth_verifier who is needed for the access_token request, but in the  end I did that logic myself with oAuth, this combined with my server being 6 minutes off clock, I got it to work

Answer (score 1):

thanks @Brmm for the good advice, but in this case it turns out we were using different twitter accounts in the keys for authentication and the api call, because, #bonehead

Comment: Then you should post a comment below his answer, not post *an answer*.

Answer (score 1):

You can write this.

```
var tw = TwitterStrategy({                                                                          
             consumerKey: config.twitter.clientID                          
           , consumerSecret: config.twitter.clientSecret                       
           , callbackURL: config.twitter.callback_url || 'http://' + config.domain + '/auth/twitter/callback'
    },                                                                                         
         function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) { 
             Player.findOne({ 'twitter.id': profile.id }, function (err, player) { 
             if (err) { return done(err) } 
             if (!player) {            
               var player = new Player({                     
                              name: profile.displayName
                            , twitter: profile._json 
                            , twitter_token: token        
                            , twitter_tokenSecret: tokenSecret                  
                            })                         
               player.save(function (err, player) {   
                   if (err) log.error(err);                         
                   return done(err, player);
               })                                      
             }                                        
             else {             
                return done(err, player)                                  
             }                                        
           })                                          
         });
passport.use(tw);
```

and you don't need to new Oauth instance.
you can use it like this.

```
tw._oauth.post(api_endpoint, token, secret, body, "application/json",  
                        function (error, data, res) { 
                            if (error) {          
                                console.error(error)                 
                            } else {              
                                console.log('tweet sent') 
                            }                     
                        }                         
);
```

ciao!